# jQuery AJAX JSON post fails, but only incognito or safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, safari

Doing two AJAX posts, both are working fine on most browsers, phones, but not in safari, or chrome incognito.  This is the error that shows:

```
fail
www.sendsonar.com/api/v1/customers:1 POST 
POST https://www.sendsonar.com/api/v1/customers 400 (Bad Request)
www.sendsonar.com/api/v1/messages:1 
POST https://www.sendsonar.com/api/v1/messages 400 (Bad Request)
```

Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Here is a code snippet of one of them:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function (request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("Token", "token-goes-here");
  },
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://www.sendsonar.com/api/v1/customers",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    'phone_number': phone,
    'email': email,
    'first_name': first_name
  }),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).success(function(data) {
  console.log('success');
}).fail(function(data) {
  console.log('fail');
});
```

Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: That error comes from your server.  Check the server logs or the response body.

Comment: I have the same issue and can't figure this out.